# How to import modules into platypus applet?

Tags: python, import

I am using platypus to bundle a python applet. I am wondering if there is a way to import modules, like math from stdlib.

Comment: If you're not dead-set on using platypus, look at py2app or [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/). I'm not an OS X developer, so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably suboptimal, but I simply add the package (the directories which actually hold the code, not an egg or anything fancy) I want to import into the bundled files list in Platypus.

This works well when you only need to add a few packages.